# Why is this conversion not working? The ordinal value is less than 255

Tags: python, encryption, unicode, vigenere

I have created the file below to encrypt a message that I have entered in a file. The encryption works up until converting the list to a string.

```
__author__ = 'Daniel'

KEYWORD_1 = 'KWIJUHRTYFGJD'
KEYWORD_2 = 'LSKJFSDKLFJSLF'

key = KEYWORD_1 + KEYWORD_2
print(key)

def get_message_to_encrypt():
    file = open   ("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\PycharmProjects\\Encryption\\TextFile.txt", 'r')
    message = file.read()
    file.close()
    return message


def convert_message(key, message, mode):
    key_index = 0
    transformed_message = []

    for letter in message:
        letter = letter.upper()
        if mode == 'encrypt':
            total_value = ord(letter) + ord(key[key_index])
        if mode == 'decrypt':
            total_value = ord(letter) - ord(key[key_index])
        transformed_message.append(chr(total_value))
        key_index += 1
        if key_index == len(key):
            key_index = 0

    return transformed_message


def convert_message_to_string(message_list):
    message_string = None
    for letter in message_list:
        message_string = ''.join(message_list)
    return message_string


    def output_message(message):
       file = open   ("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\PycharmProjects\\Encryption\\TextFile.txt", 'a')
       file.write(message)
       file.close()

   message_to_encrypt = get_message_to_encrypt()
   message = convert_message(key, message_to_encrypt, 'encrypt')
   converted_message = convert_message_to_string(message)
   print(converted_message)
   output_message(converted_message)
   print(message)
```

The contents of the file is:

> hello there my name is Daniel Devlin and I would like to say hello to you. I hope you have a really nice day.

When the program is run the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/PycharmProjects/Encryption/Encryption.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(converted_message)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

As I have said I have printed out the ordinal value for all the characters and none exceed 255. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Your file not starting a valid character ! Simple way `ignore first line`. You can test it on  `idle`

Comment: Apologies but I'm not sure what you mean. The file content starts with h. Do you mean the file name is invalid? The error seems to be getting thrown when I try to convert from the list to the string.

Comment: `"C:\\Users\\Daniel\\PycharmProjects\\Encryption\\TextFile.txt"` os procdure not equal to python file procedure(on write and read). i meaning : try open a file with python `first write some content, don't open with any os text editor`. More winos text editor adding special char to file start /end point.(related about of `encoding,EOF,system-encoding, etc...`)

Comment: Hi, I changed so as not to use the text editor. I created a message in the program created a file and wrote it to the file. I then read that, converted it and when attempting to write it to the file the error is still there. There is also an error when I attempt to print the converted string. Thanks

Comment: haven't any one declaration (for encoding) in script startup ? Like this `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` .This hint does not solve the problem check external ide(pycharm) and/or python ide encoding setting(set as utf-8).

Comment: I've tried both by adding the declaration and by checking the encoding when the program is run using import sys and then print sys.getdefaultencoding() but the error still occurs when trying to write the message to the file.